# Outlook shows an error message when idled for a long time

Tags: exchange, outlook

As mentioned in the title, "Attempt to log in to Microsoft Exchange failed" appears when using Outlook 2019 after being idled for a long time.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdKQO.jpg)

For example: When user select "Rules"->"Manage Rules and Notifications", "Attempt to log in to Microsoft Exchange failed" appears.
when an error is encountered and the following actions are performed, it will sometimes be normal

1. Restart Outlook and it will be normal.
2. Sometimes closing the error window will return to normal.
3. It will be normal after executing transmission/reception.
   The login method for Outlook is to use exchange
   The version of exchange server is 2013.
   How can I check this problem? What is the reason for this message?
   how do I confirm which part problem.exchange?network?outlook?

exchange------fortigate-----------Users

I also tried to set fortigate as below Tip, But the issue still exists
https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-Use-case-of-tcp-session-without-syn-in-firewall/ta-p/258372

Comment: I find the message as link [error message](https://gist.github.com/chengyang99/532f6fb5e301e9d50f23568752a20233)

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, I would like to confirm with you what is the specific version of exchange 2013 you are using. Could you check whether all services of exchange are running using the command Get-Service *Exchange*?
Additionally, it is recommended that you try the following troubleshooting steps:

1. A corrupted profile can cause issues with Microsoft Outlook. In such a case, you can create a new profile in Microsoft Outlook
2. Start Outlook in Safe Mode and Disable Add-ins
3. Turn off the cached Exchange mode. The issue can occur due to a large OST file or a shared mailbox downloading items in the local cache (OST file). You can turn off the Cached Exchange Mode for the shared mailbox to fix this problem.

Here are some similar posts for your reference:
[[Solved] The set of folders cannot be opened. The attempt to log on to Microsoft Exchange has failed - MS Office - Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/193496-solved-the-set-of-folders-cannot-be-opened-the-attempt-to-log-on-to-microsoft-exchange-has-failed)

[The set of folders cannot be opened. The attempt to log on to Microsoft Exchange has failed. - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/649851/the-set-of-folders-cannot-be-opened-the-attempt-to)

Comment: [exchange service](https://gist.github.com/chengyang99/6a214aab540a4cbc09f936a0f70123ec)
not only the 1 user outlook have this problem.
even the new install have the same problem